# ImportError: No module named solcx

Tags: python, python-3.x, solidity

Estoy intentando instalar solcx desde hace ya un rato, y luego de conseguir que VS Code me tome el modulo como existente, me tira el error mencionado en el titulo.
Cabe aclarar que el modulo esta instalado siguiendo su pagina de PyPi (https://pypi.org/project/py-solc-x/#description) y cuando intento ejecutar mi programa (lo dejo abajo) me dice que el modulo no existe.

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
   simple_storage_file = file.read()
   print(simple_storage_file)

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
   {
       "language": "Solidity",
       "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
       "settings": {
           "outputSelection": {
               "*": {
                   "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
               }
           }
       },
   },
   solc_version="0.8.7",
)

print(compiled_sol)
```

Y este es el error completo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deploy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
ImportError: No module named solcx
```

Desde ya gracias.

Edit (en referencia al comentario de abulafia): estoy usando Debian 11, no estoy usando ningun venv y Python (su version python3, la python2 ya viene con Debian) fue instalada en la terminal del SO, no en la de VSCode.

Comment: Estas cosas suelen suceder cuando hay más de una versión de python en el sistema, o diferentes entornos virtuales, y has instalado el paquete en uno de ellos pero VSCode en cambio está usando otro intérprete. Prueba a ejecutar el script desde la misma terminal desde la que usaste `pip` para instalarlo. Y amplía la pregunta con más información acerca de si usas virtualenv, o qué operativo usas y cómo instalaste python

Comment: @abulafia es raro, acabo de probar lo que me decis de correrlo en la misma terminal donde instale python y me tira el mismo error. Asimismo, tambien me pasa en todos los programas que hago en VSCode, me los toma todos como si estan escritos en la version 2.7, cuando en realidad tengo instalada la 3.9.2. Sabes como hacer para arreglarlo y poder usar la version 3? Gracias!

Comment: Cuando cargas en VSCode un archivo .py, abajo a la izquierda puedes leer (en la barra de estado) qué intérprete está usando (ej: Python 2.7, o lo que sea). Pinchando ahi te deja elegir otro. Suele detectar correctamente todas las versiones que tengas instaladas y te las muestra en un desplegable, pero si no sale la que quieres también puedes elegir la primera opción "+ Enter interpreter path" y navegar hasta el Python.exe que quieras usar